# How to enable Bluetooth Pairing?

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, mouse

I just bought a Logitech M240 bluetooth mouse and I've spent the better portion of my afternoon trying to figure out how to pair it with my laptop (an HP Pavilion x360 that runs Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Completely up to date, constantly making sure the darn thing is updated.) I've tried pairing the device through the system settings (where it connects for a minute and then just stops), installed Bluetooth Manager to try pairing the device through there (where I'm able to connect to the mouse and add it as a trusted device. It still refuses to "pair") and even bent over backwards sifting through 'bluetoothctl', connecting and attempting to pair the mouse via its mac address which works until I get a prompt every minute to "allow the mouse to pair with my device".)

A few things about the mouse itself:

1. It doesn't have a bluetooth adaptor that you can plug into the laptop. It's designed to connect to any device (PC, tablet, phone, etc) WITHOUT the use of an adaptor. (In other words: the adaptor's built INTO the mouse).
2. It is fresh out of the box. Brand spanking new, bought it today. This mouse has no issues connecting with other devices, purely just my laptop.

Also whenever I try pairing through the terminal, this is usually the errors I get. The one thing that I haven't seen is "Pairing Successful"

```
[LOGI M240]# pair DE:79:A1:18:CD:12
Attempting to pair with DE:79:A1:18:CD:12
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists
```

or

```
[LOGI M240]# pair DE:79:A1:18:CD:12
Attempting to pair with DE:79:A1:18:CD:12
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
[CHG] Device DE:79:A1:18:CD:12 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device DE:79:A1:18:CD:12 Connected: no
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

and no, I've never got a single "Pairing successful" prompt via the terminal. So every minute I need to go back to my system settings, click the "allow pairing" button to be able to use the mouse until that minute is up and I'm re-prompted. What am I doing wrong?